# SCTP tunable parameters for load testing

Tags: server

I am using sctp on ubuntu 10.04,with multicore cpu. I want to test load on one sctp port.Tried to change params sctp_rmem, sctp_wmem and sctp_mem.  But not able to receive maximum call/sec. With increasing number of request say  1 lacs total request with 2000 call/sec. Then all messages( 1lacs) are not exchanged. Please help me
- Which params need to be tune ?
- How to check whether buffer is full or not?

Thanks and Regards,

Abhishek Misra